# Does Azure API management service support validating JWT against ADFS?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I would like to delegate the authentications (against ADFS) of back end APIs to Azure API management service. Does the `validate-jwt` policy from Azure API management support validating JWT against ADFS? If yes, any guideline I can follow?

Comment: Hi Shuping, were you able to make this work?

Comment: NO, for now I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: My understanding is that ADFS issued JWT is RSA signed. Currently the only way to verify RSA-signed JWT in API Mgmt is using openid url. So the question is whether ADFS is openid compliant, which I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I will check my organization ADFS.